# Programming Principles and Practice: chapter 4 drill part 1

Tags: c++

I just can't seem to get this program to work properly.  I can get it to accept two integers and print them to the screen.  But I can't get the program to terminate when the '|' is used.  Once that its entered it loops infinitely.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    char counter = '\0';

    cout << "Please enter two integers and press enter. \n";

    bool test = true;
    while (counter != '|')
    {
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
        cout << "Your numbers are: " << num1 << " " << num2 << endl;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Goodbye!\n";
            test = false;
        }
        else (counter != '|');
        cout << "Enter more numbers or press '|' to exit.\n";
    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Your `while` loop doesn't change `counter` so why do you think it should work the way you described?

Comment: Also `else (counter != '|');` is not going to cause `Enter more numbers or press '|' to exit.` to always be displayed.

Comment: Please clarify (or remove) "PPP" from your title.

Comment: If you're referring to the book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup, please say so explicitly in the question. Or, better yet, change the title so it refers to the question you're asking rather than to the book that it comes from.

Comment: Use a prompt and `getch()`; Don't use `system("pause")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong condition in your while loop.  You are never changing `counter` so the loop will never end.  However you do change `test` to `false` in the while loop if the input fails.  You can change the condition of the while loop to use `test` instead like

```
while(test)
{
    //...
}
```

Since `counter` is no longer being used you can get rid of it completely.

Please note that unless you change to taking in string and parsing the input any input that will cause `cin` to fail will end the loop not just a `|`.

Comment: That helped me get the program to terminate.  The counter I just forgot about it being in there, I had tried a few different solutions and gotten things a little complicated at one point.  Thanks for the help.